# firebase.auth(...).signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I m getting Error while invoked function.
I m using LsignInWithEmailAndPassword Method.Any Special Configuration is Require?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const firebase=require('firebase-admin');
    firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


     exports.login = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


               var data = {
      email    : 'demo@gmail.com',
      password : 'demo123'
    };
    var auth = null;
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      .then( function(user){
        response.send("Authenticated successfully with payload");
      //  console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", user);
        auth = user;
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        response.send("Login Failed!");
      //  console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      });
            //  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
     });
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call `firebase.auth()` from the Admin SDK, you're getting an object of type [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth).  As you can see from the API docs, it doesn't have a method called `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

It seems you're mixing up the javascript client SDK with the Admin SDK.  There's no reason to use the client SDK in Cloud Functions.  It's supposed to be used in the browser only, since signing in only makes sense on the device that the user is actually using.

Comment: If we want to create a complete REST API Service using Cloud functions, What can be done in that case? As you can see if we need to hit an end point, we can request from Any rest client. How can we address Sign-in without using any Firebase Client SDK's?

Comment: @Ayyappa If you want to create your own sign-in system outside of Firebase, it sounds like you don't want to use Firebase at all and simply build everything yourself the way you would like it.  Firebase Auth is opinionated and does a lot of work for you, but you don't have to accept it if you want something different.

Comment: Actually, there is still a general use-case when making Rest Api's where we want to have an auth system independent of client sdk's. It would be good if firebase-admin provided it so that we don't need to implement rest api's ourselves.

Comment: @Ayyappa You can always file feedback with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Sure! Thanks Doug!

Answer (score 3):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` is only available in a browser environment. To get access to who made a particular request, you can use [`firebase.auth().getToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken) to get a JWT token, and send that along to your cloud function endpoint. Then from there you can call [`verifyIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#verifyIdToken) to get the `uid` of whoever made the request.